# Symfony2 register bundle and its routes at runtime

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony2 and am trying to figure out how to implement a database driven plugin system.  The database part is no problem, but I have no idea how to dynamically register bundles and their routes during runtime; I only know how to hard code them into the app kernel and the routing config file.  My best guess is that I would listen for a kernel.request event and in my listener register the bundles/routes...?  I have no idea about how to accomplish this, however, and and would like to see how the community would do this.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but keep in mind that the upcoming Symfony 2.1 is using the composer to manage dependencies and autoloading, which might effect what you want to achieve.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve by registering routes at runtime as well as why wouldn't you want to load all the bundles every time?